# Pecl Swoole php plugin installation fails on linux centos

Tags: linux, centos, pear, php-extension, pecl

I am tried to install swoole (a php plugin) via pecl and manually built from source. 
Both methods fail with the error

/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:37: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’,         ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:38: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:44: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘pcre’
make: *** [swoole.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed

Can anyone shed any light on this please?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i just 
yum install pcre-devel 
before running the install.